# Codeigniter (or Drupal) adds one slash after base_url

Tags: codeigniter, hyperlink, anchor

I have an application located at www.example.com/mywebsite

It was all working ok, but for some reason codeigniter decided that it's gonna screw up all my links. In config.php I have this http://example.com/mywebsite as the base_url. I'm using the codeigniter anchor function (one would expect that this is the way to go).

What happens: If I look a link with the firebug it's href attribute looks ok. But when I click it, it takes me to this kind of url: http://www.example.com//mywebsite/whatever

It just adds one slash to much after my main domain. I hope anybody has any idea what is this?

EDIT:
The website at www.example.com is on drupal. I don't know if drupal can be causing this but it's possible.

Comment: Show a example of how you are using the anchor tag.

Comment: example: <?php echo anchor('tours', 'Tour'); ?>

Comment: damn.. I need a codeigniter guru. This is a serous issue. Users can only see the front page and 404 errors.

Answer (score 1):

Put a trailing slash at the end of http://example.com/mywebsite as it is said on the config.php file.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/mywebsite/';
```

Comment: Sorry... I accepted your answer, but later found out that the problem was caused by a hosting provider... Thanks anyway...